# Making A Character Move To The Orders I Give It

Tags: javascript, user-controls

When I was coding and trying to figure out what to do, so I tried to make a character move to the buttons orders. (up down right and left) so I did what I thought would work but it didn't, so I tried to debug it. (when I debug something I often // everything and then un// one part and try to debug that part and use that debug on all the other ones I wont // this time but it will be different(I want the color )). The language is javascript. This is what I have.

```
onEvent("up", "click", function( ) {
  var currentY = getProperty("player", "y");
  console.log("currentY = ", currentY + 10);
});

onEvent("down", "click", function( ) {
  console.log("inside of onEvent - down");
  setProperty("player", "y", +3);
});

onEvent("left", "click", function( ) {
  console.log("inside of onEvent - left");
  setProperty("player", "x", -3);
});
 onEvent("right", "click", function( ) {   
 console.log("inside of onEvent - right");
  setProperty("player", "x", +3);
});
```

Comment: We're going to need some more context. What are `onEvent()` and `getProperty()`? What's the expected result vs actual result?

Comment: I'm trying to make the charter move up when I press the "up" button down when I press the "down" button (etc)

Comment: Great; we ask questions to get more details that help solve the problem. It really helps if you answer all the questions. What is "the charter"? You are setting variables here, but what do those variables do? What are `onEvent()` and `getProperty()`? What's the expected result vs actual result?

Comment: charter was a misspelling of character but I edited that and for the thrid time im telling you I want "player" to go up when I press the up button, down when I press the down button, (etc) but it either doesn't move at all or go crazy.

Comment: You never define any "player" in the code you have provided. You still haven't clarified what `onEvent()` or `getProperty()` do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice a couple of issues with your code that might be causing the problem.
Try This:

```
onEvent("up", "click", function() {
  var currentY = getProperty("player", "y");
  // You need to update the "y" property of the "player" element by subtracting a value to move it up.
  setProperty("player", "y", currentY - 10);
});

onEvent("down", "click", function() {
  var currentY = getProperty("player", "y");
  // You need to update the "y" property of the "player" element by adding a value to move it down.
  setProperty("player", "y", currentY + 10);
});

onEvent("left", "click", function() {
  var currentX = getProperty("player", "x");
  // You need to update the "x" property of the "player" element by subtracting a value to move it left.
  setProperty("player", "x", currentX - 10);
});

onEvent("right", "click", function() {
  var currentX = getProperty("player", "x");
  // You need to update the "x" property of the "player" element by adding a value to move it right.
  setProperty("player", "x", currentX + 10);
});
```

What I've changed:

For all button events, I've fetched the current position using getProperty() before updating it.
In the "up" button event, I've set the "y" property to currentY - 10 instead of just logging the value. This will actually move the character up.
In the other button events, I've corrected the values for the "x" and "y" properties.

Make sure your "player" element has the "x" and "y" properties set initially. If it's an HTML element, you may need to use CSS properties like "top" and "left" instead of "x" and "y".